# How to change a video on the press of a button

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently helping out a friend with a site he's trying to build. He does designs for "stream overlays". I'd like to create an option that changes the video shown on an html video onClick. An example for this would be [The interactive showcase on own3d.tv](https://own3d.tv/product/alphagaming-series-package). The code I've made so far is the following:

```html
<video id="alert-player" class="vid_1" 
    <source id="blank_video_alrtp" src='unknown' type='video/webm'/>
</video>
```

The above is the video's code.

````js
var alertPlayVideo = document.getElementById('alert-player');
  document.getElementById('new-follow-btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('blank_video_alrtp').src = 'https://eragedesigns.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/05/new-follower.webm';
  });
  alertPlayVideo.load();
  alertPlayVideo.play():
</script>```
/*That one was the event listener I set up*/
````

```html
<button id="new-follow-btn" >FOLLOWER<br>ALERT</button>
```

And this is the button that has to be clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `src` of `<source>` upon click, and `load()` and `play()` the video.

```js
var alertPlayVideo = document.getElementById('alert-player'); //The <video> tag
var blankVideoAlert = document.getElementById('blank_video_alrtp'); // The <source> tag inside <video> tag
document.getElementById('new-follow-btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
  blankVideoAlert.src = 'https://eragedesigns.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/05/new-follower.webm';
  alertPlayVideo.load();
  alertPlayVideo.play();
});
```

```html
<video id="alert-player" class="vid_1">
    <source id="blank_video_alrtp" type='video/webm'/>
</video>

<br>
<button id="new-follow-btn">FOLLOWER<br>ALERT</button>
```

Comment: In this example, what does the 'alert-player' do? Sorry, I'm not great at this yet :)
Also, what function does blank_video_alertp have. Sorry

Comment: @Timothy Do you want to change video of existing HTML `video` tag, or of another video tag?

Comment: @TimothyTownsend I have updated my answer. Please check if this is what you meant.